# Как отличить пустой массив от массива из пустой строки при преобразованиях при помощи `join()` и `split()`?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [];
var str = arr.join(','); // ''
var res = str.split(','); // ['']

var arr2 = [''];
var str2 = arr2.join(','); // ''
var res2 = str2.split(','); // ['']
```

Comment: в смысле? `[]` - это пустой массив, `['']` - это массив с одним элементом

Comment: @timur Я имею ввиду то что `[]` и `['']` одинаково преобразуются при помощи `join()` в `''`, после чего невозможно понять что именно было преобразовано в эту `''`. `[]` или `['']`?

Comment: а зачем вам понимать, что было преобразовано в `''`?

Comment: @timur Преобразование массива в строку и обратно может понадобиться например при записи в Web Storage или для передачи на сервер.

Comment: Сюдя по вашим операциям никак

Comment: Это как 2+2=4 и 0+4=4 как отличить что где-то было двойки а где нет

Comment: Сохраняйте исходники если вам они нужны

Comment: Наверное, в таком случае лучше использовать JSON.

Comment: Вы уверенны, что для вашей задачи необходимы именно `join` и `split`? Посмотрите в сторону `JSON.stringify/parse`.

Comment: @wololo `JSON` может вызывать подвисания из-за того что массив очень большой, `join()/split()` быстрее.

Comment: Для передачи на сервер можно просто проверить если что передать. Если есть что в массиве то передавайте тогда получив пустую строку вы поймёте что было в исходнике.

Comment: Зачем костыль если можно проверить на length и работать? Без всяких излишеств

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да, вроде очень хорошо. При сериализации в строку можно анализировать длину, и это и есть ответ что это было `[]` или `['']`. 

Comment: Еще можно рассмотреть вариант `var arr3 = [','];`...

Comment: @Yaant Ну это само собой разумеется что разделитель не должен встречаться в элементах массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто проверьте исходный массив на длину перед использованием, тем самым вы определяете что передать на сервер. Если получив на сервере массив с пустой строкой вы поймёте что было в исходнике.

Answer (score 0):

Mожно обернуть еще `push("")`/`pop()`.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду использовать `eval()`?

Comment: нет, если в массив всегда пушить пустую строку перед join-ом, а после сплита убирать

Comment: Да, тоже отличное решение если нельзя исключить пустой массив незаписью в Web Storage или неотправкой на сервер.